# how to close all ports

Tags: linux

A few days back when I scanned my PC there were no open ports and now I have 5 ports:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
631/tcp  open  ipp
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Is my security at risk? Can anyone tell me how to close all the ports to be safe? I think there is no need for those open ports

Comment: `iptables -F INPUT;iptables -P INPUT REJECT` will close all ports. But that’s probably not what you want.

Comment: As Smoke says, this is not actually a question. If your computer is supposed to never connect to anything then his instruction will help. But is that what you actually want to do? Please edit your post to clarify

Comment: so those ports all relate to open services on your computer, and you can shut them down by either stopping the services that are listening on those ports or limit their access to localhost.  Port 80/TCP is a web server so look for things like nginx or apache2.  Port 111/TCP is portmapper, generally related to things like NFS.  631/TCP is usually CUPS 902/TCP hmm VMWare possibly.  3306/TCP will likely be MYSQL.  By any chance did you do some web development on that PC recently?  The ports alone aren't necessarily a security risk but watch things like MySQL passwords or web sites on 80/TCP

Comment: Did anything change on that computer in the past 5 days? Did you install anything?

Comment: Pull out the network cable?

Comment: Are you running the scan in *exactly* the same way, and *from the same system?* Can you show us the command line you ran to get that report? (Feel free to replace any IP with [192.0.2.1](https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation) or any host name with `my-computer.invalid`.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  So the reason that ports are visible on the network is fundamentally that a program you have running on your computer has asked to make that port available on the network.

In the case of the services you've listed the following are the common services that will listen

- 80/TCP - A web server (something like Apache or Nginx)
- 111/TCP - usually relating to RPC services (like NFS)
- 631/TCP - IPPP or CUPS, a printing service
- 902/TCP - likely something relating to VMWare
- 3306/TCP - Commonly MySQL .

In and of themselves having a service exposed to the network won't necessarily damage your security, but each one provides a point of attack on your host.  So for example if you have a weak password on your MySQL service an attacker might be able to guess that.

In order to stop them listening, you have a couple of options.

1. If you don't need that service to be running on your PC, then you can stop the associated process.  runnning the command `sudo netstat -plnt` should show the listening port and the process/program name associated with it.  Ones that show the local address as `0.0.0.0` or `[YOUR_NETWORK_IP]` are listening on the network and could be contacted remotely.  So once you have a list of the services just shut them down.
2. If you do need the services but don't want them to be available on the network you can generally make them only listen on the "localhost" address.  How you do that will vary from service to service, but if you search for "binding to localhost" and the service name you should be able to find something
3. Perhaps the easiest way to address the problem is to run a firewall on the host to block inbound connections as @smokedispenser mentioned in his comment. Assuming you're using ubuntu something like [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) could be worth looking into.

what's probably happened to cause these services to start listening is that you've installed some new software which provides network services.  At a guess have you perhaps been practising web development?